# jQuery return multiple function

Tags: javascript, jquery

so, i have the following js:

```
function RHL(a,b,c)
{
  return rx.removeClass(a).addClass(b); 
  return rhpfc.html(parseInt( rhpfc.html() ) -1 );      
}
```

I am having a bit of difficult time with the formatting and syntax.

How do I combine both lines under one `return`. Also, I want to have two options: -1 or +1. So, I thought I would make `-` or `+` as `c`.

what kind of bracket do I need? (ie. 'c'1)

Comment: JavaScript functions can only return one value. Try combining the two statements into an array or the like.

Comment: I see. that was the issue. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I don't think that the return statement is necessary at all with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Without the return, I am getting undefined error in this case. :P

Comment: Instead of passing `+` or `-` try passing `1` or `-1` as `c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function RHL(a,b,c){
  return [
    rx.removeClass(a).addClass(b), 
    rhpfc.html(parseInt( rhpfc.html() ) -1 )
   ];      
}
```

then you will need to use the index 0 or 1 to use the return value..

```
var rx = RHL(a,b,c)[0];
```

or

```
var rhpfc = RHL(a,b,c)[1];
```